# Remove path constraint in object linked from another scene

Tags: animation, constraints, linked-data

I have a starship model following a path in scene A. The model is linked to scene B where I would like to do other things with it. However, the object keeps the movement animation from scene A. There are no keyframes in scene B, and there is no path constraint applied in the linked object in scene B.

I also tried hitting U and chose to delete animation data.

How should remove the animation?

Comment: maybe try to deparent it?

Comment: Thank you, worked. I removed the follow path constraint in scene A, unlinked the object in B and then reapplied the path constraint in A.